# How to send messages from one controller from another with delegates?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I've got an UDPSocket in one of my controllers i know that i have to use delegates. What functions i have to add to make it access my udpsocket from another controller?

it would be great to use smth like

```
[controller1.udpsocket sendData:data toHost:host]
```

but i know its not good, what to do instead of it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DownLoadImageDelegate<NSObject>
@required
-(void)ImageDownLoaded:(UIImage*)image;

@end


@interface DownLoadImage : NSObject 
{

    id<DownLoadImageDelegate> mDelegate;
    NSURLConnection *mConnection;
    NSMutableData *mData;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) id<DownLoadImageDelegate> delegate;
@end

//InViewController class 

DownLoadImage *imageDownLoad = [[DownLoadImage alloc]init];
imageDownLoad.delegate=self;
//and implement the delegate method declared in DownLoadImage class in ViewController class as

-(void)ImageDownLoaded:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSLog(@"Image%@",image);
    [mImageView setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: and how can i call this function?

Comment: i think i understood, Do i need to set this methods public?

Comment: In DowmLoadImage class call the delegate method once finish downloading as fallows:- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:mData];
 if(mDelegate && [mDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ImageDownLoaded:)]){
   [mDelegate ImageDownLoaded:image];
 }

 [mConnection release];
 [image release];
 [mData release];
}